# sql mariadb, error syntax over partition

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

When executing a query I get following error

> '[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '(PARTITION by kd_lv3) as max_date , row_number()
>   OVER (PARTITION by kd_' at line 6'.

Query :

```
select kd_lv3
, nm_lv3
, kd_lv2
, kd_lv1
, date(update_date) as update_date
, max(date(update_date)) OVER (PARTITION by kd_lv3) as max_date
, row_number() OVER (PARTITION by kd_lv3) as rownum
from akun_lv3_dump
```

What should I do to resolve the error?

Comment: I do not understand, why query over (partition by kd_lv3) always generates an error.
whether in mariadb the syntax of over partition is different from the others.
Please help me.

Comment: What version are you using? Row_number was introduced in 10.2

Comment: i use version 10.1.28-MariaDB. 
whether in this version does not support over partition syntax?

Comment: you are as capable of answering that as anyone else

Comment: `OVER ( PARTITION ...)` syntax is not available until MariaDB 10.2 or MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

I would have commented instead of answer, but I don't have points enough.

The SQL looks good to me, but I dug into it and your query has:

```
(PARTITION by kd_lv3) as max_date
```

while your error has:

```
(PARTITION by kd_akun_lv3)
```

So, if the query you supplied is correct, that isn't what is being run - and you are possibly testing some older sql. Not sure what your environment is, but perhaps something needs refreshing...